# How to get single backslash instead of double backslash with encode("unicode-escape")?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

Get unicode point of character `Ä`.
Python3 version.

```
>>> str="Ä"
>>> str.encode("unicode-escape")
b'\\xc4'
```

How to get the single backslash format `b'\xc4'` instead of `b'\\xc4'` as my output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want, so I'll give you a few options.

Get the (Unicode) code point of a character as an integer:

```
>>> ord('Ä')
196
```

Display the integer in hex notation:

```
>>> hex(ord('Ä'))
'0xc4'
```

or with string formatting:

```
>>> '{:X}'.format(ord('Ä'))
'C4'
```

However, you talk about backslashes and show the bytestring `b'\xc4'`.
This is the Latin-1 encoding of `'Ä'` (all characters with a Unicode codepoint below 256 can be encoded with Latin-1, and their byte value equals the Unicode codepoint).

```
>>> 'Ä'.encode('latin-1')
b'\xc4'
```

This is a bytestring of length 1.
It is displayed in a way in which you could type this character, ie. using an escape sequence with backslash-x and a two-digit hex number.

The "unicode-escape" codec produces these four ASCII characters (`\`, `x`, `c` `4`), but not as `str`, but as a `bytes` object (because `str.encode()` returns `bytes` by definition).
To get a backslash in a str/bytes literal, you need to type two backslashes, so the `repr`esentation form also uses two backslashes:

```
>>> 'Ä'.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\xc4'
```

The "unicode-escape" codec is very Python-specific and I don't see a lot of applications; maybe if you want to write your own pickle protocol or parse fragments of Python source code.